# Continuous increase in database id sqlite

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, sqflite

This is how I create a database.

```
CREATE TABLE $_tableName(
        id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        category TEXT,
        content TEXT,
        date TEXT
        )
```

When I delete any data, id continues from where it left off. For example, I have id data in the range 1-10. When the content number 3 is deleted from the database, the newly added value id becomes 11. I want to save the new value in the blank 3 field.

```
  Future<int> add(NoteDbModel saveDbModel) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(_tableName, saveDbModel.toMap());
  }

  Future<int> remove(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete(_tableName, where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }
```

Comment: This is the [documented](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) behavior.  If you want to reuse old values, you'll need to provide them when you insert based off your own logic.

Answer (score 1):

The intended purpose of an **id** is to uniquely **id**entify a row.

SQLite treats tables, other than virtual tables and WITHOUT ROWID tables, that have a column defined as `INTEGER` with `PRIMARY KEY` in a special way. The column is an alias of what could be classed as the SUPER KEY, that is it is an alias of the hidden **rowid** column.

SQLite favours (is optimised for) use of the **rowid** or an alias thereof. When scanning/searching the underlying index that scan/search can be up to twice as fast.

As you have found if, when inserting a row with such a column, and that column is provided a value, then the value gets generated. It is simply along the lines of `max((SELECT id FROM theTable))+1`.

So if any but the last row is deleted then that value remain unused (**see the following notes as this is not actually the whole truth**).

- unless the highest ever possible value gets used, when SQlite will attempt to find an unused BUT lower value

  - unless AUTOINCREMENT is used coded when instead an SQLITE_FULL error is raised.

    - AUTOINCREMENT for SQLite is inefficient and does not determine the generation of a monotonically increased generated value.

Trying to use the column for any other purpose, such as wanting it to be specific values to suit a human, will often result in issues, such as the one you have raised.

**Demo** (including using insert to insert with first unused id, **even though not recommended**)

- note just the bare SQL, which could be adapted

:-

```
/* Just in case demo environment was not cleaned up */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo;

/* The demo table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, another_column TEXT DEFAULT 'whatever');

/* Add some data (ids 1 -10 in all likeliehood) */
WITH 
    cte(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cte LIMIT 10)
    INSERT INTO demo (another_column) SELECT 'somedata' FROM cte
;
SELECT rowid,* FROM demo; /* RESULT 1 - Original data */

/* Drop odd numbered ids */
DELETE FROM demo WHERE id % 2;
SELECT rowid,* FROM demo; /* RESULT 2 - After deleting odd # ids */

/* replicate issue i.e. add 7 new rows (ids 11-17) */
WITH 
    cte(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cte LIMIT 7)
INSERT INTO demo (another_column) SELECT 'newdata #'||x FROM cte;
SELECT rowid,* FROM demo; /* RESULT 3 - ids not filling free/unused ids */

/* Revert to original with dropped odd ids */
DELETE FROM demo WHERE id > 10;
SELECT rowid,* FROM demo;

/* Insert new row using the first unused id, if one */
WITH
    cte_extraValueToInsert(newValue) AS (SELECT 'the new data to be inserted 1'),
    cte(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cte LIMIT (SELECT max(id) FROM demo)),
    cte_missing(expected) AS (SELECT x FROM cte WHERE (SELECT id FROM demo WHERE demo.id=x) IS NULL ORDER BY x ASC LIMIT 1)
    INSERT INTO demo (id,another_column) VALUES(
        (CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT expected FROM cte_missing) 
            THEN (SELECT expected FROM cte_missing) 
            ELSE (SELECT max(id)+1 FROM demo) 
        END),
        (SELECT * FROM cte_extraValueToInsert)
        )
;

/* Insert second new row using the first unused id, if one */
WITH
    cte_extraValueToInsert(newValue) AS (SELECT 'the new data to be inserted 2'),
    cte(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cte LIMIT (SELECT max(id) FROM demo)),
    cte_missing(expected) AS (SELECT x FROM cte WHERE (SELECT id FROM demo WHERE demo.id=x) IS NULL ORDER BY x ASC LIMIT 1)
    INSERT INTO demo (id,another_column) VALUES(
        (CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT expected FROM cte_missing) 
            THEN (SELECT expected FROM cte_missing) 
            ELSE (SELECT max(id)+1 FROM demo) 
        END),
        (SELECT * FROM cte_extraValueToInsert)
        )
;
SELECT rowid,* FROM demo;

/* Clean up DEMO environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo;
```

- cte's are **C**ommon **T**able **E**xpressions, they are effectively a temporary table with a lifetime as per the execution of the SQL/Query

  - they can even be used for recursion (some of the cte's in the code are recursive). You may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

**Demo Results**

1. After initial population of row rows with generated ids:-

[image]

2. After deletion of odd ids

[image]

3. After adding 7 rows with generated ids (i.e. the issue) i.e. **WRONG**

[image]

4. After deleting the **WRONG** inserts (back to 2))

[image]

5. After inserting two rows using the **fix**(sic) SQL

[image]

- Note that this is just an in-principle demo, it has not been exhaustively tested (e.g. using it when there are no unused). Use of this is not recommended.